# How to read X509 Signing Certificate content from string in .net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have X509 Signing Certificate inside of a string like:

```
var signingCertificate = -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\nMIICTjCCAbegAw.........-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now I want to read the content of this certificate. i know we can do it using X509Certificate2 object but that reads from file directly. Is there anyway to read the content from string?

Comment: X509Certificate accepts a byte array as constructor argument containing the certificate data. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.1#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate__ctor_System_Byte___

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert your string to byte array, and create a X509Certificate2 object from it.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signingCertificate);
var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
```

Comment: thanks, it works. Just one thing, I had to convert the string to char[] first.

Comment: @Ask: It works just exactly as he's shown, and there is no `X509Certificate2` constructor that accepts a char[] as an argument.

Comment: No I mean  GetBytes method in  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signingCertificate); accepts char[]